# Reversed resize jquery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, resize, rotation

How to do a reversed resize with jquery UI? (Enlarge instead of minimize and vice versa) (needs to be to done after rotation done be the user - it could be any degrees) because no consideration is take into account when rotating divs

newItem is a div.

```
newItem.resizable({
     handles: {
    'nw': '.nwgrip',
    'ne': '.negrip',
    'sw': '.swgrip',
    'se': '.segrip'
    },
    aspectRatio: true,
    resize: function( event, ui ) {  

                //Original size
                var origWidth = ui.size.width;
                var origHeight = ui.size.height;                        

                //Fumbling in the dark... ...How do I do "reversed" resize?
                //Tried this:                    
                ui.helper.css("width", (origWidth - ui.helper.css("width") *-2) + "px");
                ui.helper.css("height", (origHeight - ui.helper.css("height") *-2) + "px");                        



         }
    });
```